# Understanding static implicit operator the right way

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I had a brilliant thought, that does not seem to be so brilliant afterwards, but maybe I don't understand the whole thing correctly.

I have a class, that stores some numbers. Some other functions/methods need int's and some need double's. So I thought I can create a class with a precision conversion implicitly.

```
public class PreciseInteger
{
    public double PreciseValue {get; private set;}
    public int RoundedValue {get; private set;}

    public PreciseInteger(double value)
    {
        PreciseValue = value;
        RoundedValue = (int)Math.Round(value, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }

    public static implicit operator PreciseInteger(int number)
    {
        return new PreciseInteger(number);
    }

    public static implicit operator PreciseInteger(double number)
    {
        return new PreciseInteger(number);
    }

    public static implicit operator int(PreciseInteger number)
    {
        return number.RoundedValue;
    }

    public static implicit operator double(PreciseInteger number)
    {
        return number.PreciseValue;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return PreciseValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

And the class that uses this class is really a simple property storing class that does not much. So now I use somthing like

```
double myValue = myClass.StoredValue1 / myDivider;
```

But here I only get the integer value. I don't want to use an explicit casting (like `Convert.ToDouble` or `(double)`). So how could I make sure that the precise value is used and not the rounded one? Or did I misunderstand the whole concept and that doesn't work at all and I would have to use something like `MyClass.MyDouble` and `MyClass.MyInteger` values?

Edit: Ok, if I first say `int newInt = myClass.StoredValue1` I get a rounded integer and if I use `double newDouble = myClass.StoredValue1` I get the precise floating point number. But isn't there a way to say that one of them is always preferred?

Comment: the point of strictly typed and/or compiled language is that you know what value you will expect a variable to contain. If you like to have your numeric variables to not have distinction between int and double, then you'll like php/python. Other advantage of strictly typed language is that you can have things like int8, int16, int32 etc (integer in 8bit, 16bit etc), this (maybe) decrease memory space needed to store variables (since float/double is usually 32bit/64bit/128bit)

Comment: Not related to your question, but I wouldn't call this a "brilliant thought". I feel like using a class like this can get confusing _real quick_. I also feel like this should be a struct rather than a class...

Comment: If this should better be a struct has not crossed my mind till yet, because its just a thought written down. ;) I cannot and will not use another language (how could I change the language of existing projects just because one question wasn't as I thought it would be? Strange answer... But I found out, that when I divide by 2.0 instead of 2, the compiler takes the double instead of the integer.

Comment: All of the built in implicit operators are *lossless*. I'd be surprised using your class that a loss of precision, via conversion to int, can happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/` operator is defined for both `int` and `double`:

```
double operator /(double x, double y);
int operator /(int x, int y);
```

These two overloads are both applicable when you do:

```
// assuming myClass.StoredValue1 and myDivider are PreciseIntegers
double myValue = myClass.StoredValue1 / myDivider;
```

because you defined an implicit conversion to `int` and an implicit conversion to `double`. However, the `/` that takes `int`s is actually a [*better function member*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#better-function-member), because `int` is a [*better conversion target*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#better-conversion-target), so the compiler always chooses the second overload.

One way to work around this is to define your own `/` operator for `PreciseInteger`:

```
public static PreciseInteger operator /(PreciseInteger number1, PreciseInteger number2) {
    return number1.PreciseValue / number2.PreciseValue;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
double myValue = myClass.StoredValue1 / myDivider;
```

Comment: I didn't knew that you can "overwrite" the operators. Nice new information, thanks. :)